# Postgres logical replication gets stuck at synchronized 's' state and does not move to 'r' state

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-15

I am currently trying out logical replication in postgres for upgrading postgres between major versions. Some tables which are part of a subscription gets stuck at 's' state of pg_subscription_rel. I tried removing the above mentioned tables from the publication and created a new publication with the tables which had the status 's' and created a new subscription for the above mentioned publication, in that case again some tables go to the 'r' state and some still remain in 's' state. On repeating the process again and again I am somehow able to get the tables to r state, but I am not able to understand why the replication gets stuck in the older publications at 's' state

```
max_replication_slots : 75 in publisher and subscriber
max_worker_processes: 60 (in subscriber)
max_logical_replication_workers: 55 (in subscriber)
```

Comment: Perhaps it just takes longer than you care to wait? Anyway, is there anything in the subscriber's log file?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, It is in the same state for more than 48 hrs and also the tables which get stuck do not have frequent writes. The subscriber's log file contains "synchronization worker for <table_name> has finished". But how does it go to the ready state when I create a new subscription for the same table?

Comment: Yes, that is strange. Unfortunately I cannot guess what might be wrong.